# Watermark on image randomly gets gray artifacts

Tags: php, gd, bitnami

I have the task to develop a plugin for WordPress that adds watermark to uploaded images using PHP. WP hosted on AWS Bitnami. They all need to be exactly 800x800px so I upscale/downscale the source image and then add the PNG watermark.

For some reason, most of the time images end up with terrible grey artifacts on them. 5% of the time they are perfectly okay, I could not see any patterns that lead to success.

This is what happens:

Image with failed watermark
[image: This is a broken image]

Image with good watermark
[image: This is okay image]

This is my code:

```
function add_watermark($resized_image) {
    
    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
    
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng( '/transparency-award-watermark.png' );
    
    imagealphablending($watermark, false); // Saw that on StackOverflow, didn't help
    
    imagesavealpha($watermark, true); // That one too
    
    $info = getimagesize($resized_image);
    
    if(max($info[0], $info[1]) != 800) {
        resize_image($resized_image);
    }

    if( $info[2] == IMG_JPG or $info[2] == IMG_JPEG ) $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($resized_image);
    if( $info[2] == IMG_PNG ) $image = imagecreatefrompng($resized_image);

    $sx = imagesx($watermark);

    $sy = imagesy($watermark);

    imagecopy($image, $watermark, imagesx($image) - $sx, imagesy($image) - $sy, 0, 0, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));
    
    imagejpeg($image, $resized_image, 95);

    imagedestroy($image);
    
    imagedestroy($watermark);

}

function resize_image($orig_image) {

    $info = getimagesize($orig_image);

    if( $info[2] == IMG_JPG or $info[2] == IMG_JPEG ) $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($orig_image);
    if( $info[2] == IMG_PNG ) $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($orig_image);

    $source_imagex = imagesx($source_image);
    $source_imagey = imagesy($source_image);

    $dest_imagex = 800;
    $dest_imagey = 800;

    $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_imagex, $dest_imagey);

    imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            $dest_imagex, $dest_imagey, $source_imagex, $source_imagey);

    imagejpeg($dest_image, $orig_image, 100);

}
```

Comment: Not sure I would call this an “artifact”, it looks more like the complete image rendering process stopped/broke at some point, and so the whole rest of the image from that position on is messed up. Did you start by checking the error logs for anything related? How much memory can your scripts use, and did you try and increase that already?

Comment: Hey CBroe, I'm not the sys admin of the server, I advised the person responsible for this to increase the memory, he told me it's set to 512M

Comment: Did you check (as CBroe pointed out) the error logs?

Comment: Still waiting for access to logs :/